# Django Rest Framework Djoser - saving JWT tokens in httpOnly cookies

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

Hey I'm looking for the correct way to implement saving JWT tokens in httpOnly cookies using JWT

I'm not sure if thing I did is right.

Changed Default authentication class in setting.py and added cookies settings

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "authorization.authentication.JWTCookiesAuthentication",
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
...
"AUTH_COOKIE": "access_token",  # Cookie name. Enables cookies if value is set.
    "AUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN": None,  # A string like "example.com", or None for standard domain cookie.
    "AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE": False,  # Whether the auth cookies should be secure (https:// only).
    "AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY": True,  # Http only cookie flag.It's not fetch by javascript.
    "AUTH_COOKIE_PATH": "/",  # The path of the auth cookie.
    "AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE": "Lax",
}
```

Created custom authentication backend in authentication.py

```py
class JWTCookiesAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)

        if header is None:
            raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE']) or None
        else:
            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            return None

        validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
```

and added cookies in response in my view

```py
class EmailTokenObtainPairView(TokenViewBase):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except AuthenticationFailed:
            raise InActiveUser()
        except TokenError:
            raise InvalidToken()

        response = Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        response.set_cookie(
            key=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["AUTH_COOKIE"],
            value=serializer.validated_data["access"],
            expires=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME"],
            secure=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE"],
            httponly=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY"],
            samesite=settings.SIMPLE_JWT["AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE"],
        )

        return response
```

But what about refresh token and will that handle requests? Will it use cookies while sending request? Also what about using my custom backend in drf-spectacular?

Thank you.